# <a> href concat own domain plus another domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when click this is loaded:
http://localhost:3000/www.anotherwebsite.net

How do I just load [www.anotherwebsite.net](http://www.anotherwebsite.net)?

```
<a href={post.domain} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
    Another Website
</a>
```

Comment: Prepend protocol, e.g. `http://` or just `//` to use the protocol of the current page.

Answer (score 1):

A URL that doesn't start with a `/` or is scheme-relative will be treated as a relative path.

Prefix the domain with `http` or `https`:

```
<a href={'https://' + post.domain} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href={'https://' + post.domain} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
    Another Website
</a>
```